# ВСЁ - какая это часть речи?

Tags: морфология, части-речи

ВСЁ - какая часть речи? Конкретно в этом тексте: "а те расходились всё дальше и переходили..."
Вроде определительное местоимение, но в этом предложении оно явно выступает в роли чего-то другого... Я вся в сомнениях, может местоимённое наречие, предикатив или союзное слово?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, это усилительная частица.

Answer (score 3):

Лучший ответ который видел на этот вопрос. Слово всё может быть местоимением, наречием, частицей и союзом – определить, какая именно перед нами часть речи, можно только в контексте, то есть в предложении, да и то не всегда просто.

Местоимение всё – это форма среднего рода местоимения весь. 
В словаре даётся такая запись:

Большой толковый словарь 
1. ВЕСЬ, всего, м. ; ВСЯ, всей, ж. ; ВСЁ, всего, ср. ; ВСЕ, всех, вин. неодуш. : все; вин. одуш. : всех. мн. ; местоим. прил.
Кстати, помета прил. , а в других случаях сущ. и числ. после пометы местоим. означает, что данное местоимение соотносится с прилагательным (существительным, числительным) , то есть отвечает на вопросы прилагательного и указывает на признак (на вопросы существительного или числительного и указывает на предмет или количество) и изменяется так же, как и часть речи, с которой данное местоимение соотносится. То есть местоимение весь (пишу в начальной форме) , соотносящееся с прилагательным, отвечает на вопрос какой? , указывает на признак предмета и, как и прилагательное, изменяется по родам, числам и падежам.

Итак, слово всё – местоимение в предложениях типа: 
Я отдыхал всё лето. 
Я проспал всё первое отделение концерта.

Наречие всё имеет следующие значения (примеры употребления наречия всё – в самой словарной статье) : 
ВСЁ. I. нареч. Разг. 
1. Всегда, постоянно. Я всё забываю, как его зовут. Вы всё в разъездах. С утра до вечера всё на ногах. *Не всё коту масленица (Погов.) . 
2. До сих пор. Уже ночь, а его всё нет. Закройщица всё больна? 
3. Только, исключительно, именно. Это всё вы виноваты. Это всё из-за тебя.

Частица всё употребляется со словами, обозначающими изменяющийся признак: 
ВСЁ. II. частица. 
Указывает на нарастание или устойчивость признака. Шум всё сильней. Больной всё слабеет. На улице всё так же холодно. Она всё такая же.

Союз всё: 
ВСЁ. III. союз. 
1. Разг. Всё-таки. Почитайте, всё не так скучно будет. С ней всё веселей, чем одной. 
2. Однако, тем не менее. Как ни стараешься, всё недовольны. *А вы, друзья, как ни садитесь, всё в музыканты не годитесь (Крылов).

Сочетания всё ж; всё же; всё ж таки могут употребляться в значении частицы и в значении союза. 
I. в зн. частицы. 
Употр. для усиления, подчёркивания смысла высказывания. И всё же согласился? Всё же успел. А (но) всё же простила его. И всё ж таки ты не прав. 
II. в зн. союза. 
Однако, тем не менее. Задача была сложной, (и, но, а) всё же удалось её решить.

Answer (score 0):

местоименное прилагательное. Группа- определительные.