# Всё — какая часть речи?

Tags: синтаксис, части-речи

*Всё надобно стараться

С потребной стороны за дело браться.*

***Всё*** — какая часть речи?
Какие грамматические свойства этой части речи проявляются в данной синтаксической позиции?

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91

Answer (score 3):

```
 Всё надобно стараться,
 С потребной стороны за дело браться.
```

1. Это **частица**, которая усиливает значение действия.  Значения "постоянно" здесь нет, нет и выделительного значения.

Например, мы говорим: *все мечтаешь, все понравиться хочешь, все не знаешь, чем заняться.* Это значение **полноты  и интенсивности** действия.

2. И это именно **частица**, а не знаменательное слово.

Частицы – это **служебные слова,** которые сообщают разнообразные **смысловые, модальные и эмоционально-экспрессивные значения** словам, частям предложения и всему высказыванию.

Comment: Согласен с ответом. Голос, или плюс.

Comment: Спасибо,  я сомневалась  в этом решении, приходилось выбирать.  Вот еще по теме  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/15536/ВСЁ-какая-это-часть-речи

Comment: А вот лично я не сомневаюсь в правильности вашего ответа.

Comment: Разных мнений было много, да еще о грамматических свойствах слова спрашивали, даже спорили.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, здесь "всё" - выделительная частица. Её можно заменить частицей "лишь". Как частица она не является членом предложения, но выполняет усилительно-выделительную роль.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, здесь "всё" — наречие. Его грамматические свойства:
(1) Значение: всегда, всё время, постоянно.
(2) Синтаксическая функция: обстоятельство.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/16119)

Comment: @Morkovkin , Почему же же не является ответом на вопрос? Вопрос: Всё - какая часть речи? Ответ: Наречие. Грамматические свойства: Значение - всегда, всё время, постоянно.

Comment: Я выбрал эту опцию из предложенных движком. А подл сомнения он попал, видимо, что "ответ" слишком краток для понимания и считаться полноценным. Но если вам это так принципиально, уточните, как вы понимаете **"грамматические свойства части речи"**? В данном случае - наречия?!

Comment: @Morkovkin Нашел такое определение: Грамматические свойства слова -это совокупность признаков:
1) значение слова как части речи (категориальное значение);
2) словообразовательная структура;
3) способность к формальному изменению;
4) абстрактные свойства (число, падеж – у имени; вид, залог, время, наклонение, лицо – у глагола);
5) синтаксическая функция.  ----- Ответил на те пункты, которые релевантны и мне понятны. Приглашаю дополнить/исправить.

Comment: Это все хорошо. Но вы же про наречие пишете. А у наречия есть только одно грамматическое (и то - под вопросом) "свойство" - неизменяемость. ----(+)--- А в каком это учебнике к грамматическим свойствам относят "значение"? Если так, то снимаю. Но что-то сомнительно, что так могли выкрутить.