# основа предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Выделите основу предложения:

"Всё надобно стараться с потребной стороны за дело приниматься"

Сколько в нём главных членов?

Answer (score 4):

Ответ верен, основа "**надобно стараться приниматься**".

Это безличное предложение, вид сказуемого - **осложненная форма СГС**: основной глагол "приниматься" и **расширенная вспомогательная модальная часть**, состоящая из слова категории состояния "надобно" и модального инфинитива "стараться"

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (по поводу фразеологизма)

Из словаря: ПРИНЯТЬСЯ,  св. 1. **за что и с инф.** Начать какое-л. дело, приступить к чему-л. П. за работу, **за дело**, за уроки. П. за уборку, за стирку. П. за еду, за обед. П. читать, делать уроки, шить. П. кричать, плакать, смеяться.

Таким образом, глагол "приняться" управляет предложной формой "за дело", которая, очевидно,  не входит в состав сказуемого. Потому нельзя считать, что приняться за дело - это фразеологизм со значением "**начать**". Приняться за дело - это **начать дело**.

Comment: Ваша ссылка на толковый словарь ничего не доказывает. Будто бы слово,имеющее самостоятельное лексическое значение, не может входить в состав фразеологизма... *Потому нельзя считать...* -- почему это "потому"?

Comment: Вы обратили внимание, что "за дело" в словаре указано в составе однородного ряда возможных дополнений. Вот как раз поэтому нельзя считать фразеологизмом.. А вообще считать можно всё что угодно, только тогда приведите определение фразеологизма, которым вы пользуетесь. На каких основаниях вы записали "приняться за дело" в  устойчивые сочетания? Может быть, вы будете так убедительны, что я с вами соглашусь. Меня тоже огорчает разнообразие мнений по этому вопросу, здесь хотелось бы четко провести границу.

Answer (score 4):

надобно стараться  за дело приниматься- осложнённое составное глагольное сказуемое, где "приниматься за дело" - фразеологизм (= начинать)

Answer (score 2):

Не уверена, но предположу:

Основа: надобно стараться приниматься.

А главных членов у меня насчиталось один: сказуемое.

"Всё" - здесь наречие в значении [всегда, постоянно](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%91).

Comment: спасибо большое, не могли бы вы ещё тут помочь?
http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418665/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8

Comment: еще раз огромное спасибо. Еще: в каких синтаксических функциях выступают формы инфинитива глагола?

Comment: Задайте отдельным вопросом, пожалуйста.

Comment: В этом сказуемом? стараться - входит во вспомогательную часть СГС "надобно стараться", Приниматься - входит во фразеологизм (инфинитив+ сущ. с предлогом), выражающий лексическое значение СГС, а вообще инфинитив может быть простым глагольным сказуемым (давай играть), входить в СГС, может быть дополнением (решил уехать),подлежащим (читать -это интересно), обстоятельством (остался ночевать, остановился попить),определением (отказался от мысли уехать)

Comment: _Людмила: инфинитив может быть дополнением (**решил уехать**)_ === По-моему, _**решил уехать**_ -- СГС.

Comment: Для меня это всегда камень преткновения. Чёрт, растолковал бы кто... ))

Comment: Да, конечно, решил уехать -СГС, а дополнение просили (о чём? ) уехать.Снова поторопилась. Забегаю на чуть-чуть, некогда, наверное, надо завязывать с этим вообще.

Comment: Niemand, а в чём камень преткновения? Вопрос задавайте, и всё  как всегда . Решил уехать - я решил, и я уехал-всё сказуемое. Они советовали (что?)уехать-они советовали, а уеду я, это уже моё действие, а не их. Дополнение. Остался зачем?-ночевать(обст-во цели). Отказался от мысли( какой?)-уехать-определение