# Синтаксические функции

Tags: синтаксис

В каких синтаксических функциях выступают формы инфинитива глагола.

"Все надобно стараться с потребной стороны за дело приниматься".

Comment: Повтор вопроса. [Синтаксические функции](http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418666/%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Comment: Некачественный повтор.

Comment: Почему некачественный?

Comment: С пунктуацией не дружит.

Answer (score 1):

*Все надобно стараться с потребной стороны за дело приниматься.* В первом случае, инфинитив "стараться" - это вторая часть составного глагольного сказуемого, во втором, инфинитив "приниматься" - это прямое дополнение.